# Display Specific Data from Database after click that item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, roles

How can I list all users that have been assigned to a role. Here is my Model.

```
namespace Comtrex_ICU.Models
{
  public class UsersContext : DbContext
  {
    public UsersContext()
      : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Membership> Membership { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("UserProfile")]
  public class UserProfile
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
  }

  [Table("webpages_Roles")]
  public class Role
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is my Controller so far: When I click on the role it does return a view with the right name of the role in that view:

```
//List all users for a role
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult List(string UserName, string RoleName)
{
    using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
    {
        var roleSelect = db.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleName.Equals(RoleName)).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(roleSelect);
    }
}
```

This is the view that displays a list of all of the roles that are saved with a link to edit, delete and list that particular role.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RoleIndex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <div class="spacerBody">
        <h2 class="admin-home-link">@Html.ActionLink("Roles", "AdminIndex")</h2>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New Role", "RoleCreate") | 
        @Html.ActionLink("Manage User Roles", "RoleAddToUser") 
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div>


            @foreach (string s in Model)
            {

                <div id="userRolesList">
                    <p class="role-p">
                        @s
                    |<span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to 
                    delete?')">
                       <a href="/Account/RoleDelete?RoleName=@s" 
                     class="delLink"> <span style="color: 
                    #f05322">Delete</span> 
                     </a>
                     </span>
                    |<a href="/Account/Edit?RoleName=@s">Edit</a>   
                    |<a href="/Account/List?RoleName=@s">List</a>

                    </p>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>

            }
        </div>
    </div>


Then when I click the List link it takes me to this view: 

    @model Comtrex_ICU.Models.Role
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "List";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2 class="admin-home-link">@Html.ActionLink("List", "AdminIndex")</h2>

    <hr/>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RoleId)





        <p>
            @Model.RoleName
        </p>
    }


How will i be able to list the specific users that corresponds to the right role?
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `@Html.TexboBoxFor` method you are asking razor engine to render textbox for that field and bind value. If you need to just display text for the field just use model property value in your `p` tag:

```
<p>
    @Model.RoleName
</p>
```

**Update:**
For listing list of roles you can use `@foreach`. For more information on razor syntax You can have a look at [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#code-try-26). There is examples for basic operations and razor syntax.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Do you know how to display the list of userNames that corespond to the right role name?